# How to adjust the responsive design to a cards

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm making a design of information cards for a website but when viewing it on a mobile device, some cards look bigger than others. How could I solve it?
At the beginning of the code, there is the CSS, then the html code

```
    <style>
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.row h1 {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3.75em;
  margin: 0.6em 0;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #c49d12;
}
.column {
  padding: 1em;
}
.card {
  padding: 3.1em 1.25em;
  text-align: center;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #c49d12 10px, transparent 10px);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0.62em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2.5em rgba(139, 118, 32, 0.15);
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  transition: 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.card .icon {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #c49d12;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.icon:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 1.5em;
  width: 1.5em;
  border: 0.12em solid #5d4b0b;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.card h3 {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  margin: 1em 0 1.4em 0;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  color: #cda928;
}
.card p {
  line-height: 2em;
  color: #625a71;
}
.card:hover {
  background-position: 0;
}
.card:hover .icon:before {
  height: 2.25em;
  width: 2.25em;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  section {
    padding: 1em 7em;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  section {
    padding: 1em;
  }
  .card {
    padding: 5em 2em;
  }
  .column {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
    padding: 0 1em;
  }
}
</style>

    <!-- Font Awesome CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css">
    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;600&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
   
    <section>
      <div class="row">
        <h1>Características</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <!-- Column One -->
        <div class="column">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="icon">
              <i class="fas fa-user-friends"></i>
                        </div>
            <h3>Capacidad</h3>
            <p>
             De 500 hasta 1,000 personas.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Column Two -->
        <div class="column">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="icon">
              <i class="fas fa-couch"></i>
                        </div>
            <h3>Mobiliario</h3>
            <p>
             Mobiliario incluido.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Column Three -->
        <div class="column">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="icon">
              <i class="fas fa-glass-cheers"></i>
                        </div>
            <h3>Bebidas</h3>
            <p>
              Refrescos y café
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      

      <div class="row">
        <!-- Column One -->
        <div class="column">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="icon">
              <i class="fas fa-money-bill-wave-alt"></i>
                                                            </div>
            <h3>Apartado</h3>
            <p>
             Apartado con $15,000.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Column Two -->
        <div class="column">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="icon">
              <i class="fas fa-utensils"></i>                                    
            </div>
            <h3>Mantelería</h3>
            <p>
              Mantelería, cubertería y vajilla.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Column Three -->
        <div class="column">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="icon">
              <i class="fas fa-wine-bottle"></i>
                                    </div>
            <h3>Alcohol</h3>
            <p>
              Descorche libre.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>



      <div class="row">
        <!-- Column One -->
        <div class="column">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="icon">
              <i class="fas fa-money-bill"></i>
                                                                        </div>
            <h3>Liquidación</h3>
            <p>
              Liquidar 20 días antes del evento
              </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Column Two -->
        <div class="column">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="icon">
              <i class="fas fa-lightbulb"></i>
                        </div>
            <h3>Iluminación</h3>
            <p>
              Videos musicales,iluminación y robótica.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Column Three -->
        <div class="column">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="icon">
              <i class="fas fa-user-check"></i>
                                                </div>
            <h3>Personal</h3>
            <p>
              Mesero, personal y maestro de ceremonias.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="row">
        <!-- Column One -->
        <div class="column">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="icon">
              <i class="fas fa-comments-dollar"></i>
                                                                                    </div>
            <h3>Mensualidades.</h3>
            <p>
              Manejamos los mejores precios a mensualidades.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Column Two -->
        <div class="column">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="icon">
              <i class="fab fa-black-tie"></i>
                                    </div>
            <h3>Entretenimiento</h3>
            <p>
              DJ y batucada.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Column Three -->
        <div class="column">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="icon">
              <i class="fas fa-fan"></i>
                                                            </div>
            <h3>Florería</h3>
            <p>
              Centro de flores
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <!-- Column One -->
        <div class="column">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="icon">
              <i class="fas fa-user-clock"></i>
                                                                                                </div>
            <h3>Servicio.</h3>
            <p>
              Servicio hasta por 5hrs.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Column Two -->
        <div class="column">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="icon">
              <i class="fas fa-cloud-meatball"></i>
                                                </div>
            <h3>Menú</h3>
            <p>
              Menú a 3 tiempos
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
       
      </div>
    </section>
```

[image]
[image]

I tried to edit certain values of the media query but I don't see any significant change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Card 'Entretenimiento' has the widest title (`h3`) making its card the widest in the bunch. Actually its `.columns` container is stretched wider than the other ones. As does card 'Mensualidades.'.

I added the following code to your CSS:

```css
.column {
    flex: 1;                        /* allow to fill parent width */
    min-width: min(15.25rem, 100%); /* at least 15.25rem, 100% when less space available*/
}
.card { height: 100% }              /* Stretch to fill parent height */
```

- Changed `h3` temporary to  `width: max-content` to find widest `h3` with *DevTools*.
- Minimum card width = 15.25rem = (~172px of widest `h3`) plus (2 x 1.25em card padding) plus (2 x 1rem column padding) = `(172px + 40px + 32px) / 16 = 15.25rem`.

You don't change the `h3 { font-size: 1.3em }` anywhere for either mobile/desktop, which means that the above `15.25rem` is the minimum required space for a card to keep all cards equally sized on all devices.

Depending on the number of cards in a single row you want on a device, you will have to fiddle with the `h3` font size per device type and modify the above `15.25rem` to your requirements.

**snippet**

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.row h1 {
    width: 100%; width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3.75em;
    margin: 0.6em 0;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #c49d12;
}

/* ADDED */
.column {
    flex: 1;                        /* allow to fill parent width */
    min-width: min(15.25rem, 100%); /* at least 17rem, 100% when less space available*/
}
.card { height: 100% }              /* Stretch to fill parent height */
/**/


.column {
    padding: 1em;
}
.card {
    padding: 3.1em 1.25em;
    text-align: center;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, #c49d12 10px, transparent 10px);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0.62em;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2.5em rgba(139, 118, 32, 0.15);
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    transition: 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.card .icon {
    font-size: 2.5em;
    height: 2em;
    width: 2em;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #c49d12;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.icon:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 1.5em;
    width: 1.5em;
    border: 0.12em solid #5d4b0b;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.card h3 {
    font-size: 1.3em;
    margin: 1em 0 1.4em 0;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 0.3px;
    color: #cda928;
}
.card p {
    line-height: 2em;
    color: #625a71;
}
.card:hover {
    background-position: 0;
}
.card:hover .icon:before {
    height: 2.25em;
    width: 2.25em;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    section {
        padding: 1em 7em;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    section {
        padding: 1em;
    }
    .card {
        padding: 5em 2em;
    }
    .column {
        flex: 1 1 50%;
        max-width: 50%;
        padding: 0 1em;
    }
}
```

```html
<!-- Font Awesome CDN -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css">
<!-- Google Fonts -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;600&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<section>
    <div class="row">
        <h1>Características</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <!-- Column One -->
        <div class="column">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="icon">
                    <i class="fas fa-user-friends"></i>
                </div>
                <h3>Capacidad</h3>
                <p>
                    De 500 hasta 1,000 personas.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Column Two -->
        <div class="column">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="icon">
                    <i class="fas fa-couch"></i>
                </div>
                <h3>Mobiliario</h3>
                <p>
                    Mobiliario incluido.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Column Three -->
        <div class="column">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="icon">
                    <i class="fas fa-glass-cheers"></i>
                </div>
                <h3>Bebidas</h3>
                <p>
                    Refrescos y café
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <!-- Column One -->
        <div class="column">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="icon">
                    <i class="fas fa-money-bill-wave-alt"></i>
                </div>
                <h3>Apartado</h3>
                <p>
                    Apartado con $15,000.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Column Two -->
        <div class="column">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="icon">
                    <i class="fas fa-utensils"></i>
                </div>
                <h3>Mantelería</h3>
                <p>
                    Mantelería, cubertería y vajilla.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Column Three -->
        <div class="column">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="icon">
                    <i class="fas fa-wine-bottle"></i>
                </div>
                <h3>Alcohol</h3>
                <p>
                    Descorche libre.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <!-- Column One -->
        <div class="column">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="icon">
                    <i class="fas fa-money-bill"></i>
                </div>
                <h3>Liquidación</h3>
                <p>
                    Liquidar 20 días antes del evento
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Column Two -->
        <div class="column">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="icon">
                    <i class="fas fa-lightbulb"></i>
                </div>
                <h3>Iluminación</h3>
                <p>
                    Videos musicales,iluminación y robótica.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Column Three -->
        <div class="column">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="icon">
                    <i class="fas fa-user-check"></i>
                </div>
                <h3>Personal</h3>
                <p>
                    Mesero, personal y maestro de ceremonias.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <!-- Column One -->
        <div class="column">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="icon">
                    <i class="fas fa-comments-dollar"></i>
                </div>
                <h3>Mensualidades.</h3>
                <p>
                    Manejamos los mejores precios a mensualidades.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Column Two -->
        <div class="column">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="icon">
                    <i class="fab fa-black-tie"></i>
                </div>
                <h3>Entretenimiento</h3>
                <p>
                    DJ y batucada.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Column Three -->
        <div class="column">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="icon">
                    <i class="fas fa-fan"></i>
                </div>
                <h3>Florería</h3>
                <p>
                    Centro de flores
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <!-- Column One -->
        <div class="column">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="icon">
                    <i class="fas fa-user-clock"></i>
                </div>
                <h3>Servicio.</h3>
                <p>
                    Servicio hasta por 5hrs.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Column Two -->
        <div class="column">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="icon">
                    <i class="fas fa-cloud-meatball"></i>
                </div>
                <h3>Menú</h3>
                <p>
                    Menú a 3 tiempos
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

In such scenarios, you have have also define a `min-height`, `max-height` or `min-width`, `max-width` depending upon the dimension that you're trying to control. Because the content is dynamic & the same goes for any images you might have in the content. Try it via using above styles, you'll get what you need.